# Find the derivative of $x^{\sin x}$, and find what slope does the graph approach as $x\to 0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I found the derivative. Here's the passages.

$$\ln(y) = \ln x^{\sin x}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln y =\frac{d}{dx}( \sin x \ln x)$$

$$y\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx}= y (\sin x \cdot \frac1x + \ln x \cos x)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^{\sin x}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}+ \ln x \cos x)\right)$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What slope does the graph approach as x -> 0?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! That first message was just a bot, and there isn't a huge problem, though it could help to describe why you have trouble with finding the slope near zero, what you've tried, etc. You can always click on the "Edit" to add more. If you haven't already, take the [Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to format math on the site.

Comment: Please learn to express the mathematics in mathjax. Other wise your solution is spot-on.

Comment: I've removed the solution-verification tag, because it was not added by the OP, and I think the OP's question is about the followup part asking about the value as $x \to 0$. (And the differential tag because it doesn't apply.)

Comment: I found the limit. lim x->0 x^sin(x) (cos (x) log (x) + (sin (x)/x)) = -∞